# System calls and EINTR error code

Tags: c, posix, interrupt, system-calls, eintr

Is there any expert out there that can help me with the following?

I have the following system calls in C:

```
access()
unlink()
setsockopt()
fcntl()
setsid()
socket()
bind()
listen()
```

I want to know if they may fail with error code -1 and errno EINTR/EAGAIN.

Should I have to handle EINTR/EAGAIN for these?

The documentation do not refer anything related to EINTR/EAGAIN but many people I see handle it.

Which is the correct?

Here is how I register signal handlers : https://gitorious.org/zepto-web-server/zepto-web-server/source/b1b03b9ecccfe9646e34caf3eb04689e2bbc54dd:src/signal-dispatcher-utility.c

With this configuration: https://gitorious.org/zepto-web-server/zepto-web-server/source/b1b03b9ecccfe9646e34caf3eb04689e2bbc54dd:src/server-signals-support-utility.c

Also here is a commit that I added some EINTR/EAGAIN handling in some system calls that I know that return EINTR or EAGAIN : https://gitorious.org/zepto-web-server/zepto-web-server/commit/b1b03b9ecccfe9646e34caf3eb04689e2bbc54dd

Comment: Depending on the platform, on the system call and the SA_RESTART flag, the system call may or may not fail with EINTR. (read in pep-0475)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which system calls can return EINTR or EAGAIN error codes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25714578/which-system-calls-can-return-eintr-or-eagain-error-codes)

Comment: I have enabled SA_RESTART. However, I have read that it should be nice to handle also EINTR explicitly.

Comment: Any other ideas? Should I handle EINTR for the calls or the SA_RESTART is enough?

Comment: `EINTR` and `EAGAIN` mean different things.  I would recommend *always* writing code to handle `EINTR`.  If you get `EAGAIN` when you didn't ask for it, there's a serious logic error either in your program or in the kernel.

Comment: EAGAIN and EINTR are most of the times for repeating the call like in fork(), read(), write() where I want to re-execute the call. Either because of a EWOULDBLOCK==EAGAIN reason or because of interruption. So you believe that it is a good practice to always handle the EINTR regardless of the system call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html -- start reading near the bottom where it talks about "Interruption of system calls and library functions..."  This is a Linux man page, but the info is pretty generally applicable to any Unix/Posix/Linux-flavored system.

Comment: I have read it, for the reffered system calls I have handled the EINTR. But, only these are the system calls that return EINTR? I do not think so. Many people handle EINTR in other system calls that their man page do not refers it. Why do the do it? Is it be good practice or is it something like magic?

Comment: Any other ideas? Should I handle EINTR for the calls or the SA_RESTART is enough?

Comment: Personally, I generally opt for checking for EINTR over setting SA_RESTART because in general I want to know when something happened.  If you see a check for EINTR on something which doesn't return it, then I would say that's either superstition or "something"s documentation is wrong (and it does return EINTR).

Comment: Yes, but what should I do now for the referred system calls that I know they don't return EINTR but people handle EINTR. Is it wrong because of documentation or superstition? I don't want to start watching the source code of the system calls in the Linux kernel...

Comment: As a rule only syscalls which are "slow" return EINTR.  Slow things are terminal I/O and things which wait (select, wait, sleep, pause, etc).  If you see somebody checking EINTR on, say, `seteuid()` then the programmer is nuts.

Comment: Great man, that was my answer! So, I have to check which system calls are time-consuming. Thank you very much!

Comment: One more question: I can handle EINTR to any system call? I have to see if the system call returns it? In your opinion is there any system call from the referred that you could handle it?

Comment: You can always do `if (somesyscall() == -1) { if (errno == EINTR) {...} }` (as long as a return of -1 indicates an error).  The only "penalty" is a few wasted cycles and future viewers of your code making fun of you if `somesyscall()` never fails with EINTR.

Answer (score 5):

Unless you install an interrupting signal handler (one installed with `sigaction` omitting the `SA_RESTART` flag, or one installed with the `signal` function on some systems) you should not expect to see `EINTR` **at all**.

Among your particular list of functions, I don't see any that could experience `EINTR` anyway except `fcntl`, and for it, only when it's used for locking. The link in John's answer should be helpful answering questions about specific functions, though.

Comment: I have installed many signal handlers with sigaction and most of these use SA_RESTART. Also the signal handlers cannot be interrupted. In some articles and threads I have read that we should also check for EINTR regardless of the SA_RESTART. I'm using HANDLE_EINTR and HANDLE_EAGAIN macros (grabbed from Chrome source code).

Comment: Any other ideas? Should I handle EINTR for the calls or the SA_RESTART is enough?

Answer (score 2):

There is a section entitled ERRORS in every man page of *NIX system call. Refer to the manual, for example : http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html. You can also use the command line `man accept` to view it.

In general, system calls that can take some time to compute can set -1+EINTR on signal delivery and short system calls not. For example, `accept()` can block your process so it can be interrupted by a signal, but `setsid()` is so short that it has been written to not be interrupted by signals.

Comment: The first thing I did was to take information from man pages and Open Group specification. All the referred system calls do not refer to EINTR or EAGAIN in their manual page. But I think that some of these or even all may return EINTR because they may use inner modules or calls that may fail with EINTR and back propagate that error. Many system calls refer to such things. For example fopen refers to man page that errno may returned by open which is used inside it... Still searching.

Comment: Also, the system call 'close' although it refers the EINTR in case of error in man page it is wrong to handle it. Usually we ignore it. This is said from Google people in Android and Chrome projects.

Comment: @EfstathiosChatzikyriakidis: If that's permitted by the standard, it will say it explicitly, as in your example of `fopen`. Note that some functions are documented *explicitly* not to be able to fail with `EINTR` though (mainly, most of the POSIX threads functions) so perhaps you can read that as implying that `EINTR` can happen in other functions that aren't explicitly documented not to be affected by it.

Comment: @EfstathiosChatzikyriakidis: Regarding `close`, that advice you found is only "correct" as a workaround for a Linux bug. See http://ewontfix.com/4/ (disclosure: my blog).

Comment: So, you believe that I would not handle the EINTR from the referred system calls since the man page do not refer anything at all? Only the socket system call refers something like: "Other errors may be generated by the underlying protocol modules.". Also, fcntl return EINTR in case of locking but I dont care for it.

Comment: fopen is not a system call, it is a library function call. It calls open behind the scene...

Comment: If you're actually using interrupting signals in your program, it may be wise to "play it safe" and check for `EINTR` even in places where you "shouldn't need to". But why are you using interrupting signal handlers if you're just going to restart the operation whenever you see `EINTR`? The whole point of interrupting signal handlers is to allow yourself to break out of blocking operations when a signal happens (but doing this has fundamental, unsolvable race conditions)...

Comment: So, regarding close is just a Linux kernel issue right?

Comment: You've made a mistake as the Open Groupe specs did specify if a call can be interrupted or not. See for `accept` http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/accept.html

Comment: close is a system call and can be interrupted.

Comment: @Jean-Baptiste Yunès: Sorry I meant access not accept.. I have handled the access system call.

Comment: @Jean-Baptiste Yunès: Close is system call and can be interrupted but in Linux kernel retrying to close the file descriptor again may lead to an error. See: https://review.webrtc.org/4759004/

Comment: @R..: I'm using signal handlers because is a server and when child processes are exited they send to the server a SIGTERM. Also when I kill the server I send the SIGTERM signal.

Comment: @EfstathiosChatzikyriakidis: I don't see any reason for those to be *interrupting* though.

Answer (score 0):

[signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) for Linux lists

```
accept
connect
fcntl
flock
futex
ioctl
open
read
readv
recv
recvfrom
recvmsg
send
sendmsg
sendto
wait
wait3
wait4
waitid
waitpid
write
writev
```

as possibly interruptible (EINTR) by no-SA_RESTART handlers and

```
setsockopt
accept
recv
recvfrom
recvmsg
connect
send
sendto
sendmsg
pause
sigsuspend
sigtimedwait
sigwaitinfo
epoll_wait
epoll_pwait
poll
ppoll
select
lect
msgrcv
msgsnd
semop
semtimedop
clock_nanosleep
nanosleep
read
io_getevents
sleep
```

as EINTR-interruptible, even by SA_RESTART handlers.

Furthermore, it lists:

```
setsockopt
accept
recv
recvfrom
recvmsg
connect
send
sendto
sendmsg
epoll_wait
epoll_pwait
semop
semtimedop
sigtimedwait
sigwaitinfo
read
futex
msgrcv
msgsnd
nanosleep
```

as EINTR-interruptible by a stopping signal + `SIGCONT`, and says this particular behavior is Linux-specific and not sanctioned by `POSIX.1`.

Apart from these, especially if the function's specification doesn't list `EINTR`, you shouldn't get `EINTR`.

If you don't trust the system to honor it, you can try bombarding a loop with your suspected system function by `SIGSTOP`/`SIGCONT`+a signal with a `no-SA_RESTART` no-op handler and see if you can elicit an EINTR.

I tried that with:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void chld(int Sig)
{
    int status;
    if(0>wait(&status))
        _exit(1);
    if(!WIFEXITED(status)){ 
        //this can only interrupt an AS-safe block
        assert(WIFSIGNALED(status) && WTERMSIG(status) == SIGALRM);
        puts("OK");
        exit(0);
    } else {
        switch(WEXITSTATUS(status)){
        case 1: puts("FAIL"); break;
        case 2: puts("EINTR"); break;
        }
    }
    exit(0);
}
static void nop(int Sig)
{
}

int main()
{
    sigset_t full;
    sigfillset(&full);
    sigaction(SIGCHLD, &(struct sigaction){ .sa_handler=chld, .sa_mask=full, .sa_flags=0 } , 0); 
    sigaction(SIGUSR1, &(struct sigaction){ .sa_handler=nop, .sa_mask=full, .sa_flags=0 } , 0); 

    pid_t p;
    if(0>(p=fork())) { perror(0); return 1; }
    if(p!=0){
        //bombard it with SIGSTOP/SIGCONT/SIGUSR1
        for(;;){
            usleep(1); kill(p, SIGSTOP); kill(p, SIGCONT); kill(p, SIGUSR1);
        }
    }else{
        sigaction(SIGCHLD, &(struct sigaction){ .sa_handler=SIG_DFL }, 0);
        if(0>alarm(1))
            return 1;
        for(;;){

    #if 1
            /*not interruptible*/
            if(0>access("/dev/null", R_OK)){

                if(errno==EINTR)
                    return 2;
                perror(0);
                return 1;
            }

    #else
            int fd;
            unlink("fifo");
            if(0>mkfifo("fifo",0600))
                return 1;

            /*interruptible*/
            if(0>(fd=open("fifo", O_RDONLY|O_CREAT, 0600))){
                if(errno==EINTR)
                    return 2;
                perror(0);
                return 1;
            }
            close(fd);
    #endif

        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and `unlink` and `access` definitely appear to be EINTR-uninterruptible (in compliance with their spec), which means an `EINTR`-retry loop around them would be unnecessary.